# Increment of field default value in mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql, increment

```
$saa = "update  aspirantdt set vote = 'vote'+1 where 'post_id' = '$id' ";
```

When i check the database the value didnt increase.
Help me out.

Answer (score 1):

yuo have a **sintax** mistake in your [`update`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) query, you are using quotest instead of backtick. Use backticks for column names and quotes for values try to change as follow

```
$saa = "update  `aspirantdt` set `vote` = (`vote`+1) where `post_id` = '".$id."' ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove quotes or use Backtics for column names.

```
$saa = "UPDATE  aspirantdt SET vote = vote + 1 where post_id = '$id' ";
```

Or with backticks

```
$saa = "UPDATE  `aspirantdt` SET `vote` = `vote` + 1 where `post_id` = '$id' ";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$saa = "update aspirantdt set vote = 'vote'+1 where 'post_id' = '$id' ";
```

means that `'vote'` and `'post_id'` are *literal strings*, not table names (that is, it will compare `$id` to the actual string `post_id` instead of the value of the `post_id` column).

What you want is backticks to quote them as a column/table name instead;

```
$saa = "update `aspirantdt` set `vote` = `vote`+1 where `post_id` = '$id' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need quotes around `vote` as its a column name, not a string.

Your SQL is probably trying to put `vote1` in an int column.